# What are the most horrible things you see in simple documents?

Tags: fun

I once saw a poster similiar to my minimal example:

[image: compiled minimal example]

The code is in the end of the post.

1. What odd things confuse you most reading a non-latex document/ presentation?
2. Where do I find the original poster which inspired this minimal example?

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}

   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   \newcommand{\changefont}[3]{
   \fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}

   \usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}

   \usepackage{cancel}

   \begin{document}
   \changefont{cmss}{m}{n}

   How to\\[-3.5ex]

   freak o\raisebox{-0.4mm}{ut}

   \hspace{-1mm}{\lsstyle your} $\cancel{\textrm{design}}$ TeX

   colleagues .
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: I hate bad kerning, giving a document that "Microsoft feel."

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes W ha t d on 't y ou lik e a bout k ern ing?

Comment: I suppose: http://xkcd.com/1015/ hits it on the nail...

Comment: Weren't we much more happy back in those days where we couldn't recognise bad kerning? I miss that

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I was answering the question "What odd things confuse you most reading a non-latex document"  Thus, my comment refers to non-LaTeX documents.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @pablos I have some original reports from our laboratory circa 1943.  State of the art science and engineering.  But here are some typographical highlights: 1cm right-hand margin; hand-pasted hand-cropped photographs; hand-written notations in figures, two different typewriter fonts and font sizes, depending on the content; one-sided printing; non-photo figures are mimeographed; underlined section titles; footnotes with superscripted symbols; distribution list handwritten on inside cover (including Dr. Veblen of IAS & D.C.Pack of Ft. Halstead); page number format: "-12 -"

Comment: @pablos  ...of course, I also have a 1972 unpublished report that shows the *complete* internet connectivity (back then, the ARPANET), with machine architectures listed, that fits on a single sheet of 8.5x11 paper.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes My comment was a joke (not so funny presumably:-) The text was arbitrary but I inserted unicode thin spaces between random letters.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Hah!  Got me!